# What do the first two numbers in the pdfborder option of hyperref do?

Tags: hyperref

for example,`\hypersetup{colorlinks=false,frenchlinks=true,pdfborder={0 0 2}}` makes the border 2 pixels, but what do the first two numbers do? I tried several values, but could see no difference.

Comment: There is nothing on the manual about it. Perhaps Heiko han explain. Might simply be that this is just the syntax

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is answered by the [PDF specification](https://wwwimages2.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/pdf/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf) (PDF 32000-1:2008):

> **Border**
>
> (Optional) An array specifying the characteristics of the annotation's
>   border, which shall be drawn as a rounded rectangle.
>
> (PDF 1.0) The array consists of three numbers defining the horizontal
>   corner radius, vertical corner radius, and border width, all in
>   default user space units. If the corner radii are 0, the border has
>   square (not rounded) corners; if the border width is 0, no border is
>   drawn.
>
> (PDF 1.1) The array may have a fourth element, an optional dash array
>   defining a pattern of dashes and gaps that shall be used in drawing
>   the border. The dash array shall be specified in the same format as in
>   the line dash pattern parameter of the graphics state (see 8.4.3.6,
>   "Line Dash Pattern").
>
> EXAMPLE             A `Border` value of [ 0 0 1 [ 3 2 ] ] specifies a
>   border 1
>                       unit wide, with square corners, drawn with 3-unit
>                       dashes alternating with 2-unit gaps.
>
> NOTE          (PDF 1.2) The dictionaries for some annotation types
>   (such
>                 as free text and polygon annotations) can include the `BS`
>                 entry. That entry specifies a border style dictionary that has
>                 more settings than the array specified for the `Border` entry.
>                 If an annotation dictionary includes the `BS` entry, then the
>                 `Border` entry is ignored.
>
> Default value: [ 0 0 1 ].

Comment: well, this gets me partway. In LyX I tried for the hell of it \hypersetup{colorlinks=false,pdfborder={1 1 6 [ 3 2 ]} } and this gave me the thick dashes, but I didn't see any rounded corners. I also tried with more reasonable values like pdfborder={.5 .5 2 [ 3 2 ]} and pdfborder={0 0 2 [ 3 2 ]}

Comment: @asllearner: Not every detail of the PDF specification is implemented by PDF viewers. In fact even greater details are missing. I do not even get rounded corners with much larger values and without dash array in AR9.5.5/Linux.

Comment: Fair enough. For what it is worth, I was using Acrobat  on a mac. BTW I completely don't understand the NOTE for PDF1.2 in your answer, but no matter, I think you answered my real question.

Comment: @asllearner: You have to dig deeper into the PDF specification to understand the note for PDF 1.2. A new feature, the border style (`BS`) directory is introduced in this version. For example, it allows to underline the link. It is supported by `hyperref` with option `pdfborderstyle`. See `hyperref`'s [README](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/hyperref/README.pdf), section "Link border style" for an example.

Comment: Will wonders never cease? ;-) Not as cool as rounded corners would have been, IMHO, but cool nonetheless. thx