# \hypersetup{colorlinks=false} draws no border around links

Tags: hyperref, tufte, border

The sample book of [`tufte-latex`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tufte-latex) gives no colored border around links when compiled with `\hypersetup{colorlinks=false}`. I checked that this is not a problem of the PDF viewer, so is unrelated to [the other question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/210640/no-border-around-hyperlinks-with-hyperref). How to enable colored borders around links when using `tufte-latex`?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!

Comment: Amongst others `tufte-common.def` sets `\hypersetup{pdfborder = {0 0 0}}`, try `\hypersetup{pdfborder = {0 0 1}}`

Answer (score 1):

`tufte-common.def` sets

```
\hypersetup{%
  pdfborder = {0 0 0},
  bookmarksdepth = section,
  citecolor = DarkGreen,
  linkcolor = DarkBlue,
  urlcolor = DarkGreen,
}%
```

when `hyperref` is loaded.

So in order to get the borders back, we can just restore the default

```
\hypersetup{pdfborder = {0 0 1}}
```

See also [What do the first two numbers in the pdfborder option of hyperref do?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/175385/35864)

MWE

```
\documentclass[nobib]{tufte-book}
\hypersetup{pdfborder = {0 0 1}}
\begin{document}
\url{http://www.example.com}
\end{document}
```

[image]